# Transform date represented as String to Date in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am using [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) and I need to transform a date.
How can I transform a date in String format (e.g. 14/09/1980) to the same but in date format in VB.NET?

I would like the datetime format to insert it into a SQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET):

```
' Assume the current culture is en-US. 
' The date is Feburary 16, 1992, 12 hours, 15 minutes and 12 seconds.
Dim myDateTimeValue As String = "2/16/1992 12:15:12"  
Dim myDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeValue)

' Reverse month and day to conform to a different culture.
' The date is Feburary 16, 1992, 12 hours, 15 minutes and 12 seconds.
Dim cultureGB = New CultureInfo("en-GB", True)
Dim myDateTimeValue As String = "16/2/1992 12:15:12"  
Dim myDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeValue, cultureGB)

' Dsiplay the date in DD/MM/YYYY format
Debug.Print Format(myDateTime ,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(VS.80).aspx

In [VB6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic):

```
dim dt as date
dim s as string
s="10/09/2009"
dt = cdate(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! And if my date is in the european format? dd/mm/aaaa

Comment: But if i try to print myDateTime is in the american format...how can i print it (and insert in the database) in the european format? Thanks